# Show json result in Textbox ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I want to know that how can I get the following json result in textbox instead console.log in asp.net C# ?

```
<script>

        var apikey = {
            key:'XXX'
        }

            request('GET', 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global-metrics/quotes/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=' + apikey.key).then((r1) => {
                var x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);
                console.log(x1.data.quote.USD.total_market_cap);
        }).catch()

        function request(method, url)
        {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open(method, url);
                xhr.onload = resolve;
                xhr.onerror = reject;
                xhr.send();
            });
        }
        </script>
```

Thx everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('textboxId').value = x1.data.quote.USD.total_market_cap;
```

you can have:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textboxId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Sometimes your js code could be executed *before* the rendering of the asp.net page has been completed, so it is better to add the js to the end of the body, or use jquery to wait the completion of the rendering phase.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   document.getElementById('<%=textboxId.ClientID %>').value = x1.data.quote.USD.total_market_cap;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If x1 contains the JSON string, after the line (if you use JQuery)

```
var x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);
//Put this
$("#<%=textboxId.ClientId%>").val(x1);
```

Comment: thx for your replay.but i want to put x1.data.quote.USD.total_market_cap in textbox

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('textboxId').value = x1.data.quote.USD.total_market_cap;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn how to use the formatting tools, so that you post code correctly formatted. The help for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also the code should be formatted as code.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.